# Rmarkdown hyperlink created from a chunk

Tags: variables, hyperlink, r-markdown, chunks

I would like to create a hyperlink in an RMarkdown document that changes according to the value of a variable located in a chunk.  for example

```
variable <- "questions/ask"
http_address <- glue::glue("https://stackoverflow.com/{variable}")
```

[Click to reveal](`r http_address)

In the html document I would like to hover over "Click to reveal" so that the link is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.  However the above code doesn't work.  Any tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Using chunk option `results="asis"` and `cat` you could do

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
date: '2022-04-19'
---

```{r results='asis', echo = FALSE}
variable <- "questions/ask"
http_address <- glue::glue("https://stackoverflow.com/{variable}")
cat("[Click to reveal](", http_address, ")")
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to include the link in the text:

```
`r paste0("[Click to reveal](", http_address , ")")`
```